# zlib get gzip-file-size before compressing

Tags: c, gzip, zlib

I have the following problem:
I'm using zlib in C to gzip files. The compressing (using `z_stream`, `deflateInit2`...) is no problem, but I need to know the size of the gziped file before I compress it. Is this possible or is the only option I have to count the bytes while compressing?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to know the compressed size before compressing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I need to know the size of the gziped file before I compress it

If you mean that you need it to compress (perhaps to allocate a buffer to hold the data), then you are mistaking, the whole point of `z_stream` is to let you compress input chunks in output chunks.

> is the only option I have to count the bytes while compressing

Yes, you need to apply the compression algorithm to know the resulting size.